# Use delete_user_meta

Tags: wordpress

I want to delete my usermeta in table database but give nothing. it give me an error because its not array expected string parameter

```
function remove_meta(){
$role = 'client'; //Select user role
$users = get_users('role='.$role);

global $wpdb;
    $stats = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT ".$wpdb->prefix." group_clients.client_id
    FROM ".$wpdb->prefix." group_clients 
    WHERE ".$wpdb->prefix." group_clients.group_id IN (1, 2, 5, 6) 
    ", $users); // Fetch data by selective group ID


    $stats = array();
    if (is_array($stats) || is_object($stats)){




      //foreach ((array) $stats as $stat){
      foreach ($stats as $stat) {
          delete_user_meta($stat->ID, 'terms_and_conditions');
                }
          echo 'Fini!';
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code you are doing confusing code. Do not do sql query unless it is really required.

```
$args = array(

'role'         => 'customer', //client or whatever you required
); 
//geting all user
$users = get_users( $args );
foreach ($users as $result)
{
  //each user id
  $userId = $result->ID;   
  if($userId != '')
  {   
    //getting all user meta of particular user
    $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $userId );
    if(is_array($all_meta_for_user))
    {
        foreach ($all_meta_for_user as $key => $value) {

            $terms  =get_user_meta($userid,'terms_and_conditions',true);
          if($terms !=''){
          delete_user_meta($userId, 'terms_and_conditions');

          }
        }
    }
 }

}
```

with hook

```
add_action('init','deletedata');

function deletedata()
{
 if(!is_admin())
    return;
 if(!current_user_can('manage_options'))
   return false;

 $args = array(

    'role'         => 'customer', //client or whatever you required
 ); 
 //geting all user
 $users = get_users( $args );
 foreach ($users as $result)
 {
    //each user id
    $userId = $result->ID;   
    if($userId != '')
    {   
        //getting all user meta of particular user
        $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $userId );
        if(is_array($all_meta_for_user))
        {
            foreach ($all_meta_for_user as $key => $value) {
                # code...
                 $terms  =get_user_meta($userid,'terms_and_conditions',true);
          if($terms !=''){
          delete_user_meta($userId, 'terms_and_conditions');

          }
            }
        }
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering, but this code will appear in back-end  and there is condition only specific user in specific group can effect delete function.

Comment: tthe code is running very well but the issue it now delete every user.  I use sql because need to fetch only spesific user.



 I need to delete usermeta from all users in groupID 1,2,5,6  spesific in metakey 'terms of condition'

Comment: So you mean to say yo want to delete those use who have terms of condition meta meta key am i right?

Comment: yeah and only effect user who belong to group where we assign before, like my first code only effect all users in groupID 1, 2, 5, 6. that ID store in database.

My code give me an error Expected parameter string 1, Array Given

Comment: Check answer now sorry for formatting. I am online from mobile so not able to format it properly

Comment: Thank you it run to fetch $terms based on role 'customer'.  but it still fetch all user with role 'customer'. My problem it's more complicated because after I fetch all users I need to filter it by groupID because not all users belong with same groupID. so I can choose with groupID I need to delete usermeta. but I will find out.!! beside do sql query. thanks!!